# onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent fired many times on rememberMe login (Grails)

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0, grails-plugin

Got the spring-security-core onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent Closure set up in Config.groovy to update the lastLogin field of a user, which works as long as an interactive login is performed.
If a rememberMe login is performed, the event gets fired many times, which leads to ConcurrentModificationException(s).

Only workarounds so far I found was:

- do not use rememberMe
- check if the lastLogin against the current time to decide whether to perform another update or not.

Example:

```
onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   User.withTransaction {
   def user = User.get((Long)appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
   if (user.lastLogin && new LocalDateTime().toDate().time - user.lastLogin?.toDate().time < 5000) {
      println "ignoring double fired onAuthenticationSuccessEvent"
      return
   }
   user.lastLogin = new LocalDateTime()
   user.save(flush: true)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea why the onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent is fired many times when using rememberMe?

Comment: Fixing this by using Burts recommended User.lock():

Comment: See 18842863  


    onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
     User.withTransaction {
      User user = User.lock((Long) appCtx.springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
      user.lastLogin = new LocalDateTime()
      user.save()
     }
    }